# django on Pycharm professional edition

Tags: django, pycharm

Can someone please guide me on How to use Django on Pycharm ?
Any descriptive steps or any link to videos would be very helpful..

I am using Python 2.7 with pycharm 4.5.4

Comment: what do you want to know? Have you ever used an IDE?

Comment: Yes I have used Pycharm as an IDE for python, but I wanted to know how do you use Django on Pycharm, what are the steps involved ?                                            Yes I created a Django Project but was not able to understand the steps that i need to take to build a small app.

Comment: I added the usual steps I do when I start new django project with pycharm

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a virtual [environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-virtual-environment.html)
2. Create a [new Django project](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/django-project-settings.html)
3. Add [local interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/project-interpreters.html) for your project

It's simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. create github repository
2. create virtualenv
3. clone github repo into your virtualenv folder
4. inside github repo folder, create new django project
5. open the folder with pycharm
6. setup python interpreter [image]
7. Enable Django support [image]
8. setup Project Structure if needed [image]
9. Switch to Django Template Engine [image]

Have fun with Pycharm! it is an awesome IDE